# jQuery minify duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a working jsFiddle that shows content based on drop-down value. How can I minify the jQuery so that I don't have to repeat myself for each 'port'. At the moment I have done 2 'ports' but it will take a while to populate the remainder.

http://jsfiddle.net/d4pvz51v/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("select").change(function () {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "all") {
            $(".auckland").hide();
            $(".tauranga").hide();
            $(".all").show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "auckland") {
            $(".all").hide();
            $(".auckland").show();
            $(".tauranga").hide();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "tauranga") {
            $(".all").hide();
            $(".auckland").hide();
            $(".tauranga").show();
        }
    });
}).change();

$('.auckland-link').click(function () {
    $('select option:contains("Auckland")').prop('selected', true);
    $('.auckland').show();
    $('.tauranga').hide();
    $(".all").hide();
});
$('.tauranga-link').click(function () {
    $('select option:contains("Tauranga")').prop('selected', true);
    $('.auckland').hide();
    $('.tauranga').show();
    $(".all").hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding different handlers for each option or link you can

On change of the select, hide all elements with class `data`, then show the element with the class as the selected value
In the same way you can have a single click handler for the links, assign a common class to all of the link elements then add an `data-*`(`data-el` in this case) to specify the target elements class name. In its click handler read the data value and set it as the select element's value and then manually trigger the select's change handler which will set the proper data element visibility.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var $target = $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
    $('.data').not($target).hide();
  }).change();

  $('.data-link').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).data('el')
    $('select').val(val).change();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="ports section-padding text-center" id="ports">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>PORTS OF OPERATION</h1>

        <h3>Select a port to view information and contact details</h3>

        <select class="choose">
          <option value="all">Select Port</option>
          <option value="auckland">Port of Auckland</option>
          <option value="tauranga">Port of Tauranga</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="all data section-padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Port of Whangarei</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2 class="data-link" data-el="auckland">Port of Auckland</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2 class="data-link" data-el="tauranga">Port of Tauranga</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Eastland Port</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Port Taranaki</h2>

          <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Port of Napier</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Port Nelson</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Centre Port Wellington</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Port Malborough</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Greymouth Port</h2>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Lyttleton Port</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Primeport Tmaru</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Port Otago</h2>

          <hr />
          <h2>Southport</h2>

          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="auckland data section-padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Port Information</h2>

          <p>Port of Auckland is centrally located on the west coast of the North Island and is one of New Zealand 's key import and export ports.</p>
          <p>Port of Auckland offers nine fully serviced berths for a wide variety of cargoes and vessels. The maximum port draft is 12.5m, and for vessels in excess of 10m Dynamic Under Keel Clearance (DUKC) must be used.</p>
          <p>Port of Auckland has the ability to handle a wide diversity of cargoes including all forms of bulk products (liquid and dry), containerised, and break-bulk products (general, refrigerated or palletised), and has specialist experience in the
            handling of heavy lift and project cargoes. All wharves are supported by covered and open storage areas.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Features</h2> 
          <p>An unusual feature of the port is that it has a beach within its breakwaters adjacent to its operational area. The popularity of Ngamotu Beach is testament to Port Taranaki's commitment to safe working practices and regard for the environment.</p>
          <p>Another special feature of Port of Auckland is its "heavy lift" expertise. Auckland has a sophisticated engineering infrastructure, which evolved primarily as a result of development of the region's oil and gas industries. As the petrochemical
            industries grew many oversized and heavy cargoes were imported and exported through Port Taranaki. Specialist know-how and facilities are available through Port of Auckland for the handling of extra heavy lifts.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <hr />
          <img style="padding-top:40px;float:right;" src="img/map-taranaki.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="tauranga data section-padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Port Tauranga</h2>

          <p>Port of Auckland is centrally located on the west coast of the North Island and is one of New Zealand 's key import and export ports.</p>
          <p>Port of Auckland offers nine fully serviced berths for a wide variety of cargoes and vessels. The maximum port draft is 12.5m, and for vessels in excess of 10m Dynamic Under Keel Clearance (DUKC) must be used.</p>
          <p>Port of Auckland has the ability to handle a wide diversity of cargoes including all forms of bulk products (liquid and dry), containerised, and break-bulk products (general, refrigerated or palletised), and has specialist experience in the
            handling of heavy lift and project cargoes. All wharves are supported by covered and open storage areas.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Features</h2> 
          <p>An unusual feature of the port is that it has a beach within its breakwaters adjacent to its operational area. The popularity of Ngamotu Beach is testament to Port Taranaki's commitment to safe working practices and regard for the environment.</p>
          <p>Another special feature of Port of Auckland is its "heavy lift" expertise. Auckland has a sophisticated engineering infrastructure, which evolved primarily as a result of development of the region's oil and gas industries. As the petrochemical
            industries grew many oversized and heavy cargoes were imported and exported through Port Taranaki. Specialist know-how and facilities are available through Port of Auckland for the handling of extra heavy lifts.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <hr />
          <img style="padding-top:40px;float:right;" src="img/map-taranaki.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function manageState(hide1,hide2,show){
 $(hide1).hide();
 $(show).show();
 $(hide2).hide();
}
```

Make a method that takes in two fields to hide and one to show. Pass in the specific classes for each condition. This works since you seem to be hiding in paris and showing a single item.

Example:

```
manageState('.all','.auckland','.tauranga')
```